# Upgrade to the latest LTS ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, udev

I've the old OS installed in our server and I needed to install `nodejs` on the process I was required to update the system so I did `apt-get update` and in the process it breaks the libudev library and I keep on getting `udev requires a kernel >= 2.6.32 not started failed` when I start in result I can not login to the server via SSH or run screen command. I'm thinking of upgrading the server OS to ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  My question is how do I achieve this and what are the implications on the running applications on the server? Is there any safe way to upgrade but also ensuring the installed application runs smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific package for that, install it and run the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The upgrade will get you a new kernel, 3.2 in the case of 12.04. This means that all packages installed must be upgraded too, to versions compiled against the new kernel. Since 10.04 is now 3 years old, there might be some relevant changes to the software installed. Say that a particular application uses a different configuration method, after the upgrade you must change the old configuration to the new method.

You can [do a search](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for the relevant packages to check the versions available for 10.04 and 12.04. You can then compare what may have changed between the two.